# react js conditional rendering fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to render based on whether or not a user has logged in.
Below is my `LoginForm.js` as well as my `Index.js` and `Dashbaord.js`. I'm trying to get from `LoginForm.js` to `Dashboard.js` but it doesn't work. No errors, but the content of the `Dashboard.js` file shows for a brief moment before reverting back to the `LoginForm.js`. What am I doing wrong here?

**LoginForm.js**

```
// jshint esversion: 6
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard.js';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
        this.state = {
            pic: '//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png',
            isLoggedIn: false
        };

    }

    _login(){
        let username = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value;
        let password = document.getElementById('inputPassword').value;
        this.options = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        };
        this.props.client.login(this.options, (success, data)=>{
            if (success) {
                console.log('You are now logged in', data);
                this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
            }else{
                console.log('Details incorrect or something went wrong.');
            }
        });
    }
    handleSubmit(){
        this._login();
    }

    render() {
        let login = this.state.isLoggedIn;
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                {login ? (
                    <Dashboard/>
                ) : (
                    <div className='card card-container'>
                        <img alt='profile-img' id='profile-img' className='profile-img-card' src={this.state.pic} />
                        <p id='profile-name' className='profile-name-card'></p>
                        <form className='form-signin' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                            <span id='reauth-email' className='reauth-email'></span>
                            <input type='text' id='inputEmail' className='form-control' placeholder='Username'></input>
                            <input type='password' id='inputPassword' className='form-control' placeholder='Password'></input>
                            <button className='btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block btn-signin' type='submit'>Login</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
// jshint esversion: 6
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <article>
        <section className='text-section'>
          <h1>Dashboard</h1>
          <p>
            Welcome, you are logged in! To have a look at the code behind this application, go to Github.
          </p>
        </section>
      </article>
    )
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

And here's my **Index.js** with the `Router` in.

```
// jshint esversion: 6
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.js';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App}>
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: You should not be retrieving the values of username and password via selector functions, store them in the state and then use `onChange` functions on the `input` components. This is the react way.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that the Dashboard and Login Form are supposed to be two distinct pages of your application. Therefore you should not be embedding the Dashboard component within the Login Form component.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks for the tips! So I'll move dashboard into my `App.js` file. Then how do I get the views to correctly render? I.e. Render and stay rendered - unlike what I'm currently seeing.

Comment: I think you should have three separate components. `App`, `Dashboard`, and `LoginForm`

Comment: They are all seperate components aren;t they? I use the app component to full in the `LoginForm` component then I want to replace the loginform comp with the dashboard

Comment: Figured it out: Needed to add a `event.preventDefault()` to stop the page reloading.